Pydantic doesn't allow mutable variables to get changed with Optional
The code below is a modified version of pydantic func argument validation. and the pydantic version is 1.10.17 and I guess, not sure, this was not a problem in other versions. so please if the current code works fine with your pydantic version notify me in comments.
import inspect
import typing
from typing import get_type_hints

from pydantic import validate_arguments


def isHintTypeOfAListOfSomeType(typ):
    # ccc1
    #  detects these patterns: `typing.List[str]`, `typing.List[int]`,
    #  `typing.List[Union[str,tuple]]` or even `typing.List[customType]`
    if isinstance(typ, typing._GenericAlias) and typ.__origin__ is list:
        innerType = typ.__args__[0]
        if hasattr(innerType, '__origin__') and innerType.__origin__ is typing.Union:
            # checks compatible for List[Union[str, int]] like
            return True, innerType.__args__
        return True, [innerType]
    return False, []


def typeHintChecker_AListOfSomeType(func):
    """
    a decorator which raises error when the hint is List[someType] and the argument passed for
    that argument doesn't follow the hinting
    """

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        args_ = args[:]
        allArgs, starArgVar = getAllArgs(args_)  # starArgVar is *args variable
        hints = get_type_hints(func)
        for argName, argVal in allArgs.items():
            hintType = hints.get(argName, '')
            if argName == starArgVar:  # to check *args hints
                if hintType:
                    if not doItemsOfListObeyHinting(allArgs[starArgVar],
                                                    [hints.get(starArgVar, '')]):
                        raise TypeError(f"values passed for *'{argName}' don't obey {hintType}")

            isListOfSomeType, innerListTypes = isHintTypeOfAListOfSomeType(hintType)
            if isListOfSomeType and not doItemsOfListObeyHinting(argVal, innerListTypes):
                raise TypeError(f"values passed for '{argName}' don't obey {hintType}")

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    def getAllArgs(args):
        sig = inspect.signature(func)
        params = sig.parameters
        allArgs = {}
        argsIndex = 0
        starArgVar = None

        for paramName, param in params.items():
            if param.kind == param.VAR_POSITIONAL:
                allArgs[paramName] = args[argsIndex:]
                starArgVar = paramName
                break
            elif param.kind in {param.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD, param.KEYWORD_ONLY}:
                if argsIndex < len(args):
                    allArgs[paramName] = args[argsIndex]
                    argsIndex += 1
        return allArgs, starArgVar

    def doItemsOfListObeyHinting(argVals, innerListTypes):
        for arg in argVals:
            if not any([issubclass(type(arg), ilt) for ilt in innerListTypes]):
                return False
        return True

    wrapper._originalFunc = func
    wrapper._isArgValidatorWrapped = True
    return wrapper


def argValidator(func):
    # mustHave1
    #  the warnings for missing arguments are not clear

    # Apply Pydantic validation first
    func = validate_arguments(config={'arbitrary_types_allowed': True})(func)
    # Then apply the custom type hint checker
    return typeHintChecker_AListOfSomeType(func)

from typing import Optional, Dict

from projectUtils.typeCheck import argValidator, typeHintChecker_AListOfSomeType

p = {}
@argValidator
def func1(a: Optional[Dict]):
    a['sd'] = 3
func1(p)
print(p)
@typeHintChecker_AListOfSomeType
def func2(a: Optional[Dict]):
    a['sd'] = 2
func2(p)
print(p)
@argValidator
def func3(a: dict):
    a['sd'] = 3
func3(p)
print(p)

the result of p after func1 is {} and after func2 is {'sd': 2} and after func3 is {'sd': 3}
I want the dict to get manipulated when passed to func, but argValidator with Optional[Dict] doesn't do that but argValidator with : dict does that
note that argValidator is a combination of typeHintChecker_AListOfSomeType and pydantic's validate_arguments and validate_arguments causes this problem
note the solution should not only be specific for Optional[Dict] and should be general and work for all other possible mutable variable type to get changed when they are passed to a func
note most likely u need to suggest arguments for validate_arguments and the code should apply the typeHintChecker_AListOfSomeType functionality

import inspect
import typing
from typing import get_type_hints, Optional, Dict
from pydantic import validate_arguments

def isHintTypeOfAListOfSomeType(typ):
    if isinstance(typ, typing._GenericAlias) and typ.__origin__ is list:
        innerType = typ.__args__[0]
        if hasattr(innerType, '__origin__') and innerType.__origin__ is typing.Union:
            return True, innerType.__args__
        return True, [innerType]
    return False, []

def typeHintChecker_AListOfSomeType(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        args_ = args[:]
        allArgs, starArgVar = getAllArgs(args_)
        hints = get_type_hints(func)
        for argName, argVal in allArgs.items():
            hintType = hints.get(argName, '')
            if argName == starArgVar:
                if hintType:
                    if not doItemsOfListObeyHinting(allArgs[starArgVar],
                                                    [hints.get(starArgVar, '')]):
                        raise TypeError(f"values passed for *'{argName}' don't obey {hintType}")

            isListOfSomeType, innerListTypes = isHintTypeOfAListOfSomeType(hintType)
            if isListOfSomeType and not doItemsOfListObeyHinting(argVal, innerListTypes):
                raise TypeError(f"values passed for '{argName}' don't obey {hintType}")

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    def getAllArgs(args):
        sig = inspect.signature(func)
        params = sig.parameters
        allArgs = {}
        argsIndex = 0
        starArgVar = None

        for paramName, param in params.items():
            if param.kind == param.VAR_POSITIONAL:
                allArgs[paramName] = args[argsIndex:]
                starArgVar = paramName
                break
            elif param.kind in {param.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD, param.KEYWORD_ONLY}:
                if argsIndex < len(args):
                    allArgs[paramName] = args[argsIndex]
                    argsIndex += 1
        return allArgs, starArgVar

    def doItemsOfListObeyHinting(argVals, innerListTypes):
        for arg in argVals:
            if not any([issubclass(type(arg), ilt) for ilt in innerListTypes]):
                return False
        return True

    wrapper._originalFunc = func
    wrapper._isArgValidatorWrapped = True
    return wrapper

def argValidator(func):
    hints = get_type_hints(func)
    for param_name, param_type in hints.items():
        if isinstance(param_type, typing._GenericAlias) and param_type.__origin__ is dict:
            # Skip Pydantic validation for mutable types like dict
            continue

    # Apply Pydantic validation
    func = validate_arguments(config={'arbitrary_types_allowed': True})(func)
    # Apply custom type hint checker
    return typeHintChecker_AListOfSomeType(func)

# Example functions

p = {}

@argValidator
def func1(a: Optional[Dict]):
    if a is not None:
        a['sd'] = 3

func1(p)
print(p)  # Should print {'sd': 3}

@typeHintChecker_AListOfSomeType
def func2(a: Optional[Dict]):
    if a is not None:
        a['sd'] = 2

func2(p)
print(p)  # Should print {'sd': 2}

@argValidator
def func3(a: dict):
    a['sd'] = 3

func3(p)
print(p)  # Should print {'sd': 3}


it doesn't work, which version of pydantic do u use

Pydantic v1.8.0. If you're using a version of Pydantic prior to this, you might encounter issues as the validate_arguments function wasn't available.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
